# .htaccess RewriteEngine On Access Forbidden Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I got htaccess file, I want to use "**RewriteEngine On**" but It gives me Access Forbidden error. when I change  httpd.conf in  AllowOverride All nothing change, it gives same error (Access Forbidden). How can I configure it.
this is code in my httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This is my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ :91/Orginal/SpecialPages.php?PageName=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is it in a sub-folder.

Comment: What u mean? can u explain ?

Comment: Is you files hosted on root of you web host or inside a folder.

Comment: You mean root or subfolder.

Comment: it is in  localhost:91

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Orginal

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ :91/Orginal/SpecialPages.php?PageName=$1 [L]
```